# SCCM 2012 multiple search terms using OR statement

Tags: sccm

I have a collection of 100s of machines in SCCM 2012

I have a short list of machines that I need to add to another collection, is there any way using the search bar at the top of the collection display view to have multiple terms?  I've tried commas and semi colons.  These are machine names, and I cannot create a new query or collection as the machines have no information that seperates them in SCCM, they are seperated by which building they are in, which SCCM is not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help at all?

[Tips for Finding Objects in the Configuration Manager 2012 Console](http://blogs.technet.com/b/configmgrteam/archive/2011/06/27/tips-for-finding-objects-in-the-configuration-manager-2012-console.aspx)

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: I think the link is now archived into this (in 2023):
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/configuration-manager-archive/tips-for-finding-objects-in-the-configuration-manager-2012/ba-p/272939

Answer (score 0):

In the search bar you are very limited.
But you mention you have no information to separate them.
IP range? Operation Unit in AD?

Worse case you need create a collection with direct add's.
Very time consuming, I only use them for test cases (so a few ~10 max machines).

Answer (score 0):

FJ

I would suggest you use AD Groups to collect the required machines together and target those via a query rule in the collection membership (in collection properties).

You can use the below WQL in the query text input box by adding your own (short, not FQDN) domain and AD Group name below

```
select SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceID,
SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceType,
SMS_R_SYSTEM.Name,
SMS_R_SYSTEM.SMSUniqueIdentifier,
SMS_R_SYSTEM.ResourceDomainORWorkgroup,
SMS_R_SYSTEM.Client from 
SMS_R_System where 
SMS_R_System.SecurityGroupName = "<Enter Domain>\\<Enter AD Group Name>"
```

This does assume that AD Discovery is configured properly in your site. You should also be aware that there is a delay in SCCM reflecting changes in AD Groups.

Additionally, if you have a relatively recent Domain Functional Level, you can utilise Dynamic Groups to auto-populate the groups based on AD attributes. I haven't got this available yet, but it looks set to hot-rod SCCM management somewhat when it becomes available.

Best wishes...